# Netlogo expected agentset error

Tags: netlogo

I'm trying to create links between an "active-turtle" and a group of other turtles (which are currently stored in a list).

I want to make use of the `create-links-with` function, but am unable to without getting an error: `expected input to be an agent-set but got a list...`
This is my code `ask active-turtle [create-links-with like-list]`

I have a working solution, but I find it ugly so am looking for a better alternative
`foreach like-list [ask ? [create-link-with active-turtle]]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The very handy [`turtle-set`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#turtle-set) primitive will turn your list into an agentset!

```
ask active-turtle [ create-links-with turtle-set like-list ]
```